# MySQL not respecting 'HAVING' where aliases are used?

Tags: mysql, alias, having

I've got the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    minDate date,
    maxDate date
);

CREATE TABLE stays (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    reservation_id int,
    theDate date
);

INSERT INTO reservations VALUES (null, CURDATE(), CURDATE());
INSERT INTO stays VALUES (null, 1, CURDATE());
```

It's for a booking system that records reservations (a general container) and stays (someone for each night).

I try to run the following query to extract all reservations that have a different number of days in the database (e.g. the reservation says there should be 2 nights, but there's only 1 in the database, etc)

```
SELECT
    reservations.id   AS 'Reservation ID',
    reservations.minDate,
    reservations.maxDate,
    DATEDIFF(reservations.maxDate, reservations.minDate) + 1  AS 'numNights',
    COUNT(DISTINCT stays.id)  AS 'numStays'
FROM
    reservations
    LEFT JOIN stays ON reservations.id = stays.reservation_id
GROUP BY
    reservations.id
HAVING
    `numNights` != `numStays`
ORDER BY
    reservations.minDate
```

This works perfectly on my Windows version of MySQL (xampp), and production CentOS server, but is broken on a testing machine running version 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1. On the broken machine, it's pulling back all rows, even though the numNights and numStays columns match.

If I replace the aliases in the HAVING clause with the expressions used in the SELECT part, then it works fine, but I can't understand why it doesn't like the aliases in the HAVING clause (on this version)?

Btw, it's definitely not a no-quote/quote/double-quote/backtick issue, I've tried all combinations. I might have thought it was a charset encoding issue, but DATEDIFF() and COUNT() should be returning the same type of integers back, right? And that wouldn't explain why expressions work in the HAVING part.

I have an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/854a3/2) set up for experimenting as well... it works fine on that too. So now I'm at a loss

Comment: Your minDate and maxDate might have unpredicted value, because they are not used in `GROUP BY` and not a result of aggregation, probably it should be: max(maxDate) and min(minDate)?

Comment: Don't see how, they're linked to the reservation and the point of the GROUP is just to aggregate the stays. It won't change the reservation data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "wrong" SQL-Query, because of wrong GROUP BY. But unfortunately, this allowed mysql sometimes. Please check mySql Configuration `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score -1):

Both the tables contain only single row of data.Without 'Having' clause its returning only 1 row. [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/958b3/1). As numNights=numStays=1 , while executing 'Having' its giving nothing.I think it'll help you.

Comment: Your observation is correct, but it didn't answer my question. The point is that on my test server it's returning rows when it shouldn't.